# What is the use of the using block?

Tags: c#, using-statement

In which situation can a using block be used and what are the benefits?

```
using (some code statement here) 
{
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using blocks are only useful when utilizing objects that implement [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). (Try saying that 5 times fast). It ensures that the dispose methods of those objects are called after they fall out of scope.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(this.connString))
{
    //do stuff here
} //con.Dispose() will be called for you automatically.
```